# Is null vector always linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm trying to find the column space of $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&0\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$, which I think is $span\left(~\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}~\right)$.  Since by definition a span needs to include the null vector, this is redundant.  Would it also be correct to say that this is redundant because $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is linearly dependent on $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ (can multiply it by a scalar of 0 to reach the null vector)?  Or is that a misapplication of the concept of linear dependence?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2, \cdots, \vec v_n\}$ are linearly independent $c_1 \vec v_1+c_2 \vec v_2+\cdots+c_n \vec v_n= \vec 0$ iff $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=0$. Considering $\vec v_n=\vec 0$, we can get $c_1 \vec v_1+c_2 \vec v_2+\cdots+c_n \vec v_n= \vec 0$ by setting $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_{n-1}=0$ and taking any $c_n \neq 0$. So by definition, any set of vectors that contain the zero vector is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 5):

It is exactly as you say: in any vector space, the null vector belongs to the span of any vector.

Comment: Including the empty set!

Comment: That depends on how you define the span. If you write (as I usually do) $\text{span}\,A=\{\sum_j c_ja_j:\ c_j\in\mathbb R,\ a_j\in A\}$, then the span of the empty set is the empty set.

Comment: The span of any subset is a subspace. An empty summation is $0$.

Comment: Those are  basically two notation choices. And I'm not sure how universal they are. What benefit does that provide, as opposed to say that an empty summation is empty?

Comment: For instance (sticking to finite dimensional spaces for simplicity) that *every* (sub)space has a basis; the basis of the trivial (sub)space $\{0\}$ is the empty set, which is consistent with $\dim\{0\}=0$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami then benefit is that the span is synonymous with the smallest subspace containing the generating set (even if the set is empty.) this is nearly a universally accepted convention as far as I know.

Comment: @rschwieb: that's a benefit, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $S=\{v : v=(0,0)\}$  we will show that its linearly dependent.
let suppose that S is Linearly independent such that $cv=0$.
$c$ may not be a zero so $S$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/